# Как убрать оранжевые рамки элемента

Tags: css

Как можно убрать вот этот ужас:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Эти оранжевые рамки появляются при `focus`, как их можно сделать невидимыми/убрать?

Comment: Установите стиль для инпута    outline:none;

Comment: Рамку не стоит убирать, т.к. если пользователь будет с клавиатуры пытаться добраться до сего элемента, очень сложно будет рассмотреть, попал ли `input` под фокус, лучше измените цвет, но не убирайте совсем, как написано в ответе, и в комментарии.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Отредактируйте CSS файл:

```
input:focus{
    outline: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Лучшее решение, которое убирает подсветку у любых элементов:

```
/* Remove outline on the forms and links */
:active, :hover, :focus {
    outline: 0;
    outline-offset: 0;
}
```